# Sharepoint: Adding comments below the fields after update

Tags: sharepoint

Can I add a text below the field that shows if this field is updated?
For example, I have updated the Name, Date, and Status. There should be a text below that indicates that these fields are updated. Something that looks like this

Name: John Doe
      Modified by: Jane Doe, mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM
Date: mm/dd/yyyy
      Modified by: Jane Doe, mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM
Status: Approved
      Modified by: Jane Doe, mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM

Thanks.

Comment: "Status: Approved" - is that what you're looking for? I want to answer by saying you can add a description to each field or add an additional column called "Status" with "Approved" being one of the choices, but I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: For the example that I have given, 'Status' is a dropdown list field in the form and 'Approved' is a value in the dropdown list.

Comment: What I'm asking is if I can add a text below the fields that have been updated indicating that change has happened in the field.

Comment: Where are you displaying this?  Is this in the New Item form, Edit Form, or a Display View?  Or even a WebPart?

Comment: Couldn't you create a new field called "Updated" and have a workflow automatically set it to "Yes" if the item has been changed?  (Maybe I'm still misunderstanding...)

Comment: Can it be done in both Edit Form or a Display View? Forgive me for some additional questions as I have minimal to none working knowledge on Sharepoint. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark - it sounds like the OP is almost trying to recreate the Version History view but inline on the native List Forms. OP, there is a native feature in SharePoint (called Versioning) which will automatically track this but the Version History is not shown inline on the forms as you describe - it's accessed through a different option on the item menu. To show inline, Mark's suggestion of populating changes into an "Audit Trail" field & displaying that is a quick & easy alternative.